# Can we have user identity at Management group level?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, policy, azure-managed-identity, blueprint

We have total 130 subscriptions among 3 management groups.
We are have few private link policies for creating A record for few resources that is using system managed identities.

Due to this multiple identities is getting created which is point of concern.
And creating user identity at subscription level for 130 subscription is really not acceptable because we are deploying policies through Azure DevOps.

Any help

Comment: You could create a manged identity and grant it permission at the management group level. should not be an issue

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals) and assign a proper role to it at Management Group level.